# A symbol imported from the ifsym package is not recognized

Tags: errors, symbols, packages

I found a symbol that I am interested in in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) list, where it is noted that the symbol is part of the `ifsym` package.

However, when I try to use the symbol, thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\begin{document}
\[
a \SmallSquare b
\]
\end{document}
```

the document fails to compile, and I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.5 a \SmallSquare
                   b
```

---

EDIT: It was suggested in a comment that I load the package with the `geometry` option. So I tried it (`\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}`). The good news is that now the document compiles successfully. The bad news is that the symbol that gets printed is wrong:

[image: With the geometry option the printed symbol is an ampersand]

Comment: @campa: Thanks. I tried adding the geometry option, but it's still not right. See my edit above.

Comment: See edited answer. They are text mode commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `ifsym` package defines only a generic `\textifsymbol` macro. Specific abbreviations are declared in different subsets which can be loaded by the options `clock`, `weather`, `alpine`, `misc`, `geometry`, `electronic`. The geometric shapes must be loaded by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for correct scaling in sub/superscripts
\begin{document}
\[
a \textnormal{\SmallSquare} b
\]
\end{document}
```

The Comprehensive Symbol List lacks this detail.

Note that the symbols are text mode, so they will fail in math mode. As an example, `\SmallSquare` expands more or less to

```
\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{ifgeo}\selectfont \symbol{96}
```

The font switching stuff is useless in math mode and `\symbol{96}` is all is left, leaving the @.

Comment: @egreg Of course... Actually I should know it... `:-/`

Comment: @egreg I was slightly puzzled that the expansion of `\textnormal` is unchanged with or without `amsmath`. I had forgotten that `amstext` does `\let\nfss@text\text`...